# Most expensive design Vs Most recent design

Tags: sentence-construction

> In the past, making structures quake-resistant meant firm yet
> flexible
> materials, such as steel and wood, that bend without breaking. Later, people tried to lift a building off its foundation, and insert rubber and steel between the building and its foundation to reduce the impact of ground vibrations. The most
> **expensive/recent** designs give buildings brains as well as concrete and steel supports, called smart buildings, the structures respond like living organisms to an earthquake's vibrations. When the ground shakes and the building tips forward, the computer would force the building to shift in the opposite direction. The new designs should offer even greater **resistant
> /security** to cities where earthquakes often take place.

My Approach

In the first blank, I am unable to find the difference that would be more appropriate

In the second blank, as per definitions I could see the following meanings and found resistant to be more appropriate because the new designs offer greater resistant/protection to cities.

resistant --> Immune to /immunity/protect

security --> safety

Can anyone guide me on the approach? Thanks in advance

Comment: You say, *"I ... found resistance to be more appropriate"*. However in the actual passage, the word you give is not "resistance", it is  "resistant". Have you mis-typed the word?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Thanks edited the message

Comment: If "resistant", which is an adjective,  was typed correctly, then the only acceptable answer is "security" because it is a noun.

Answer (score 1):

Expensive buildings are not necessarily the smartest ones. There existed expensive buildings like mansions and deluxe apartments even before the concept of smart buildings came into existence. Hence the correct choice will be ***recent***, because it is something more of a new technique that has developed or is developing over the years.

We use the noun form in such cases depicting qualities. Hence I believe it should be ***resistance*** (as said by chasly-supports Monica in their comment to your question).

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/resistance),

**resistance** - *The ability not to be affected by something, especially adversely*

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP has rewritten the key word, and it now says **resistant**, I still +1 your answer because it's clear and it's correct notwithstanding the OP's edit.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the approach is grammar.  If the words have different grammatical functions sometimes only one will fit.

Sometimes the approach is meaning.  If the words have different meanings, only one matches the context.

Expensive and recent are both adjectives, so you can't tell which one from the grammar. The difference is meaning (and the meanings are completely unrelated). You must look at the full context

Here the context is "In the past"...."Later"...  So now what follows?  "expensive" or "recent"?

The second gap you have a choice between an adjective "resistant" and a noun "security".  Which word type would fit in "offer greater .... to cities".  Does the verb "offer" need a noun or an adjective as its object?